# Complex select in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a requests table that has id, type and amount. Type can be A or B

I need to generate a table that is like this

> id, sum of amount, sum of amount of type A, sum of amount for type B

I can use

```
select id, sum(amount) from requests group by id;
```

But I don't know how to get the rest of the two columns

Comment: Can you please add schema, sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 4):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT id, 
       SUM(amount) sum_amount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'A' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) sum_a,
       SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'B' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) sum_b 
FROM requests 
GROUP BY id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, splitting this in to columns is not the pattern SQL is designed for.

The natural pattern is to have a column describing which Type the row is for. Then, if new types appear in the data, you get new rows rather than having to code new columns (which SQL doesn't natively support).

```
SELECT
  id,
  type,
  SUM(amount)
FROM
  requests
GROUP BY
  id,
  type
WITH
  ROLLUP
ORDER BY
  id,
  type
```

The `ROLLUP` ensures a row is also generated for all the types combined, as well as each type individually.